# Best practice to create base layout for each activities

Tags: android, android-activity, layout, fragment

What is the best practice to create base layout for each application activities. If i have only static header and footer i could use single layout file, but i need also to change base background if it stored in DB. Extending each activity some base activities when i could do that also not resolve my problem because i have some activities which extend ListActivity, Activity or other.

Comment: use <include in your xml file to use single xml in other layout files

Comment: And how to get background image from database in that xml?

Comment: I think i must use fragment, and when i just mus create another activity just copy that fragment of code that is responsible for creating view